# Save data from edit Text within custom alertdialog to excel file with apache poi

Tags: android, apache-poi, android-alertdialog

This question might have been asked several times (about returning value from alert dialog) but i just couldn't get this thing to work (the flow in android application was fine but it just couldn't save the data to the excel files), I've tried several methods posted in SO but still no luck and in a deep frustration atm.

I have some suspicion though. I think it's because i accessed both etOne and etTwo from within the inner class that makes it somewhat unreadable?

The snippet of my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
alertDialog.setTitle("Enter the data below");
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog, null);

//I think the problem comes from here?
final EditText etOne = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etOne);
final EditText etTwo = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etTwo);
//----------------------------------------------------------------

alertDialog.setView(dialog)
    // Add action buttons
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // Save One and Two to excel file
                            try {
                                FileInputStream file;
                                HSSFWorkbook workbook;

                                file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));

                                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

                                HSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook.getSheetAt(2);
                                int row;
                                Cell cell;

                                row = ((KaryawanActivity) getActivity()).position;

                                cell = sheet2.getRow(row).getCell(1);
                                cell.setCellValue(etOne.getText().toString());

                                cell = sheet2.getRow(row).getCell(2);
                                cell.setCellValue(etTwo.getText().toString());

                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //Open Semasa Activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), SemasaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("filepath", fileName);
                            intent.putExtra("evaluator", evaluator);
                            intent.putExtra(THEME, theme);
                            intent.putExtra("KaryawanNo", KaryawanNo);
                            intent.putExtra("KaryawanPos", ((KaryawanActivity) getActivity()).position);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, and i forgot to point out that there are no problem with the excel file. I already created the row and the cells of the excel files. Other function have no problem saving data at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ah forget it, it's my own mistake anyway. I forgot to set the write the workbook of course it'll never save. My bad -_-

For those who need it, the complete code goes this way, and accessing the EditText from within inner class is doable (although i doubt this is a good way of doing it).

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
alertDialog.setTitle("Enter the data below");
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog, null);

//I think the problem comes from here?
final EditText etOne = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etOne);
final EditText etTwo = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etTwo);
//----------------------------------------------------------------

alertDialog.setView(dialog)
    // Add action buttons
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // Save One and Two to excel file
                            try {
                                FileInputStream file;
                                HSSFWorkbook workbook;

                                file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));

                                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

                                HSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook.getSheetAt(2);
                                int row;
                                Cell cell;

                                row = ((KaryawanActivity) getActivity()).position;

                                cell = sheet2.getRow(row).getCell(1);
                                cell.setCellValue(etOne.getText().toString());

                                cell = sheet2.getRow(row).getCell(2);
                                cell.setCellValue(etTwo.getText().toString());

                                file.close();

                                FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
                                workbook.write(outFile);
                                outFile.close();

                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //Open Semasa Activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), SemasaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("filepath", fileName);
                            intent.putExtra("evaluator", evaluator);
                            intent.putExtra(THEME, theme);
                            intent.putExtra("KaryawanNo", KaryawanNo);
                            intent.putExtra("KaryawanPos", ((KaryawanActivity) getActivity()).position);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();
```